# Cannot resolve module babel-preset-es2017/polyfill

Tags: webpack, babeljs

When I try to run my app using webpack with es2017 I get following error:

```
ERROR in ./app/app.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel-preset-es2017/polyfill' in C:\Users\mjarn\WebstormProjects\zombie-cat-production\app
 @ ./app/app.js 3:0-39
```

My webpack setting:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'es2017', 'react'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

My entry file import statements:

```
import 'babel-preset-es2017/polyfill'

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
...
```

How do I make it work?

Comment: Maybe you should add a resolve fallback

  resolveLoader: {
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')]
  },

Comment: In newer versions of `babel-preset-es2017`, `/polyfill` no longer exists. If I may ask, where did you see the recommendation to use it? I see that the README at https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-es2017 is out of date with the git repo https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2017, so perhaps it was that?

Comment: @loganfsmyth So what is the solution?

Comment: Loading `babel-polyfill` would be the easiest I believe?

Comment: The official README is out of date. I will add my solution as an answer in a minute so that other people can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Official README is out of date. I decided to add preset `stage-0` instead in my `.babelrc` file.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [ "babel-plugin-rewire" ]
    }
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config` stayed as it was.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'babel',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Trying to get Object.values to work, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The correct readme for babel-preset-es2017 seems to be this: https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2017

See https://github.com/babel/babel.github.io/issues/946